# ElasticSearch: What does it mean if an index's health is 'red'?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I'm so sad to have to ask this here, but I can't find this information anywhere in the ElasticSearch docs for ES 2.2/3. If I `_cat` all the indices on our single node, a couple of them show up with a health of 'red' - what does this mean? I know what it means for a cluster, but not an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that at least one **primary shard** of that index is not available. For clusters that have more than one node, this means that the replica shards of that shard are also missing all.

But you have one node only, so the cluster (and the indices) are already `yellow`.

Comment: Thank you - I don't suppose you know if there is a way to find out why the primary shard is unavailable?

Comment: That's  whole investigation by itself :-). And there can be countless reasons for such a failure.